# Shift the xaxis coordinates in flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

[image]

The Sept-2012 is at the origin and not visible on the axis. I want to shift to the right so I can see the sept 2012 on the axis.

Comment: Can I see your `ticks array?` are ticks calculated or hard coded?

Comment: @captain I am using `xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%b-%Y"}` to convert the date in (yyyy-mm-dd) to time in milliseconds server side to achieve the x coordinates

Comment: please post your `tick array` and `data` here

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `min` property of the axis:

```
xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%b-%Y", min: new Date(2012, 8, 1).getTime() }
```

(`new Date(2012, 8, 1)` is 2013-09-01 in Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The scaling is probably correct, but it doesn't have enough space to draw the label.  You can try using the x-axis min option to set a slightly lower min, or you can set the labelWidth option on the y-axis to increase the amount of room available on the left.